# Auditing AS 400 DB2 library user access

Tags: security, db2, users, audit, iseries

As part of the testing to check for authorized users having access to applications and libraries on AS 400 systems, I need help to figure out a list of users having access to applications hosted on the AS 400 systems, need to understand is there way to list down users grouped to access specific libraries for certain applications and all users given access to and revoked access and also the privileges assigned to each users, over a period of time for the testing.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the specific application. Most AS400 DB2 applications have initial  Application Administration which configures privileges assigned to each application user. The administration role is normally a DBA or programming staff responsibility. To extract a list of Groups and/or users accessing specific functions speak to the DBA or Application Administrator.